# How to get data from firebase when page loading using vuejs?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to get current user data from firebase to display details in profile page.

Here i am trying get data from firestore, when page loading. My table structure : users => Current user UID => email, firstname, lastname, businessname, etc.

I have added functionality to get data from firebase when profile page loading but does not work. error showing in console product.data().firstname is not function.

And also i did not get any console output firebase data retrieved or not?

here is my code:

```
<template>
<section class="what-we-do">
<div class="container-2" style="padding-top: 150px;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="saving-process-crd">
            <div class="saving-process-inner">

                  <avatar :fullname="currentUser.email" size="96" >
                  </avatar>
                  <h4>Siva NSN</h4>
                  <h6 style="color:grey;">{{currentUser.email}}</h6><br><br>

                  <div class="card-columns" >
                    <div class="card" style="border: none; text-align: justify;">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">First Name:</h5><br>
                        <h5 class="card-title">Last Name:</h5><br>
                        <h5 class="card-title">Email ID:</h5><br>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="border: none;">
                      <div class="card-body" style="float: left; text-align: left;" >
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{product.data().firstname}}</h5><br>
                        <h5 class="card-title">Mobility</h5><br>
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{currentUser.email}}</h5><br>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>

      </div>


</section>


 </template>
 <script>

import Avatar from 'vue-avatar-component'
import database from '@/database'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'


export default {
  name: 'Profile',

computed:{
currentUser (){

  return this.$store.state.currentUser
}
},

components: { 

Avatar

 },
 data () {

    return {

      profileData:{
        email:null,
        firstname:null,
        lastname:null,
        secondaryEmail:null,
        businessName:null
       }
    }


},

methods:{

readData(){

      const firestore = database.firestore();
   firestore.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).
  onSnapshot(function(doc){

        console.log('current data:', doc.data())

          var newData = doc.data()

        this.profileData.push(newData)

      })

 }

}





   }
   </script>
```

main.js code:

here i am i have user authstatechanges of current user.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

 import router from './router';

 import 'bootstrap';
```

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import './assets/styles//base-style.css';

```
import store from '@/store'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'

Vue.config.productionTip = false


let app

const initialize = () => {

if (!app) {

app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
router,
store,
render: h => h(App),


 })
}

}

 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

 if(user) {

 store.commit('setCurrentUser', user)
 } else {
 store.commit('setCurrentUser', null)
 }

 initialize()

 })
```

console output: [image]

How to get data when page loading from firebase database. any help much appreicated pls..

Comment: u are pushing data to object... push is array method

Comment: also u are not invoking readdata function, u just defined. Call it in created or mounted lifecycle method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are number of things you have to adjust,

1. instead of fetching data using a method, try to add the code to a life cycle hook method, which will fire before you mount the data to dom, more precisely saying, use `created` lifecycle hook
   https://vuejsexamples.net/vuejs-created/
2. Then you are populating the data to the template using `currentUser` which is taken from the vuex store,
   `return this.$store.state.currentUser`, but in your firebase function you are setting the data you fetch to a data property which is `profileData` which is not used in the template.
3. You are pushing to `profileData`, but it's not an array it is a object and you cant push to an object.

> So better flow is, fetch data using `created` lifecycle hook, then
>   either
>
> 1. store(mutate) the received data to the `store.state.currentUser` then it might work.
> 2. else update the `profileData` and replace the template with `profileData` instead of `currentUser`

Try this one,

1. Create a `created` lifecycle hook and move the firebase code to that. and assign the profileData object to the fetched Data.

```
    created() {
      const firestore = database.firestore();
      firestore.collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).
              onSnapshot(function(doc){

                    console.log('current data:', doc.data())

                      var newData = doc.data()

                    this.profileData = newData;

                  })
            }
```

2. Then replace the `currentUser` in template to `profileData`.

ex : `<h6 style="color:grey;">{{profileData.email}}</h6><br><br>`

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering!! i am new to vue.j. can you suggest me how to do.? I have updated question too and added main.js

Comment: i have changed but still facing issue. can check this link whether i have updated correctly or not from your updated answer https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vy0-tShXe1JV_dccWhU4TVmCdy7-V234

Comment: `created` should come outside methods

Comment: now i can get console data of current user. but nothing displays in screen. in console i got error like this "Property or method "profileData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render"

Comment: in the data property you don't have a profileData field now, instead you have email, and other fields separately, so what you can do is, assign the email and other fields to corresponding value you fetch from firebase, then replace the places where you have mentioned `profileData.email` to just `email`

Comment: can you check it out ..https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Vy0-tShXe1JV_dccWhU4TVmCdy7-V234

Comment: check this link, I have done the changes that you need
https://jsfiddle.net/CharlesRajendran/m4wva6de/2/

Comment: still email is undefined https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nsM1TKQpSUjLTsVsXbDOMzw4PeyVWdqA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you have email in your object right, i mean in newData

Comment: check the typeof newData or try `newData[émail']`

Comment: it prints data when i do like this  this.email = newData.email

              console.log('profile email',  this.email) but it does not print   this.profileData.email = newData.email

              console.log('profile email',  this.profileData.email)

Comment: share some screenshots

Comment: can you check this https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tCpwP6jYlwwulMrg_bNsTW25MBK-ykA4/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wHLh7a9UZnLX7hSS4zvXj0r0mRE4CtGT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193020/discussion-between-gokublack-and-pvdev).

Comment: Modify it to this one
https://jsfiddle.net/CharlesRajendran/m4wva6de/6/