# Using v-switch in vuejs and firebase object in a component, how to show the value from firebase in the v-switch

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I need v-switch starts with the value from firestore object, here ( {{usuario.tabVisibleCatalogo}} ) i got the rigth value from firestore:

```
<template>
 <v-btn @click="estadoPublico" flat>

{{usuario.tabVisibleCatalogo}}
```

buet here, i don´t get the value from firestore when the component start or re render, it shows the value from data:

```
  <v-switch v-model="switch1" :label="`Publicado: ${switch1.toString()}`"></v-switch>
 </v-btn>
</template>

<script>
 export default {        
    data: () => ({
      switch1: false,
    }),

computed: {
      ...mapState('sesion', ['usuario']),      
    },
methods: {

async estadoPublico () {       
                try {
                      await db.collection('usuarios')
                            .doc(this.usuario.uid)
                            .update({
                                    tabVisibleCatalogo: this.switch1,          
                            })
                }...
        },

}
</script>
```

This is my object in firestore:

> usuarios / usuario: {
> tabVisibleCatalogo: this.switch1,
> }

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to retrieve data from your Firestore collection, I would suggest to implement a mounted (or created method) on your vue.js script. This [article](https://donlalicon.dev/blog/get-data-cloud-firestore-universal-nuxt) provides steps on getting data from Firestore from the two commonly used methods: mounted & asyncData. I would recommend you look into this article as you may find some correlations between those examples and what you are currently working on.

I managed to find similar posts that you may find relevant for your particular inquiry. Have a look at [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472002/vue-js-cannot-retrieve-data-from-cloud-firestore/62472744) & [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034086/how-to-get-data-from-firebase-when-page-loading-using-vuejs)